# How can I run my node script using a shell script file

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am creating a personal site using node. It is going to help me keep track of the ebooks that I am reading.

At the moment, I need to `cd` to the project folder and run `node server.js`.

I thought I'd create a shell script and then I'd just have to double click on the file. The file would have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
node server.js
```

The first error I've got was that `server.js` is not found at the root directory, I fixed that by typing the full back, then it threw same error for all the dependencies in the application

(I have never used shell scripting)

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: why not have the shell script cd into the app directory to run it?

Comment: Oh, yes! I didn't think of that @SterlingArcher. But still (now that I asked the question) is there another way, where even if I move the project into a different location, the script would still run

Comment: Could you please share the error log? Normally, it not has any issue with dependencies location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are Linux user.

1. Set the path in your `$HOME/.profile`

> export MY_COOL_NODE_APP=$HOME/nodejs/app/cool_app

2. Now your script will run as:

> node $MY_COOL_NODE_APP/server.js

So in case if you move your app, you will need to update your `.profile`

Comment: Thanks. this works, but I don't know why! is there something I could read to understand what you did there. Thanks

Comment: the `.profile` is the config file to be read by shell on every interactive login (i.e. when you open your terminal or when you use pseudoterminal). So in this case when u launch your terminal the variable `MY_COOL_NODE_APP` get exported, hence can be used by any other bash script you will run.

Comment: I suggest you read this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ to get more insight into bash scripting, and some general introduction to Linux system